# How to make upside-down inverted triangle pattern

Tags: javascript

I want to make a pattern like in the picture, but the result is different.

[image]

Attempt:

```js
var stars = '';

for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    stars += '*';
  }
  stars += '\n';
}

console.log(stars);
```

Comment: Please accept an answer as the solution if it solves the problem to close the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill in spaces in the beginning when needed:

```js
let stars = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    stars += (j >= i) ? '*' : ' ';
  }
  stars += (i === 9) ? '' : '\n';
}

console.log(stars);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stars = '';
// number of spaces
var k = 2*10 - 2;

// Outer loop to handle number of rows
// n in this case
for (var i = 10; i > 0 ; i--) {
  // Inner loop to handle number spaces
  // values changing acc. to requirement
  for (var j = 0; j < 10-i; j++) {
    stars += ' ';
  }
  k = k-2
  // Inner loop to handle number of columns
  // values changing acc. to outer loop
  for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
    stars += '*';
  }
  stars += "\n";
}
console.log(stars);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).